# Is this a useless use of `cat`?

Tags: bash

I can't figure out how to make the following work without using cat.  I'm not worried about the forked process or anything, it just unsettles me:

```
$ printf "<format specification string>" $(cat source-file.txt)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  You can accomplish the same thing, without creating a new process for `cat`, with:

```
$ printf "<format specification string>" $(<source-file.txt)
```

Comment: that looks more complicated. so i would say "no, your use of cat is not useless, but there is a more concise but lesser known way". +1 for the insight.

Comment: The OP *did* tag the question with **bash** but note anyway that this is bash-specific and will not work in other Posix shells.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb `$(<file)` is not only more concise, but also has better runtime performance, as it doesn't involve a fork.

Comment: @Charles i doubt that that makes any difference when reading a file from disk or for anything else in bash.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Depends on where you're at. Writing an inner loop on an embedded platform where you're pressed for cycles, it could be measurable.

Comment: @Charles that sounds funny to me. If I am "pressed for cycles", most definitely I would *not* write that loop in bash! lol

Comment: @Charles: Writing such a program on an embedded platform in Bash? A very realistic scenario.

Comment: @DeadMG ...*shrug*. It's something I've done in the past, but then, I'm a little weird. :)

Comment: And +1 to @je4d for the vocabulary lesson!

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is useless use of cat, I would still use `cat` for outputting contents of a file instead of `<` in this case because it eliminates the possibility of overwriting the input file due to a redirect character typo (`>`)

Comment: @AdamLiss What is the relevance of unit testing to my comment?

Comment: A unit test would catch a typo, so you wouldn't need to choose a known-inefficient (not to mention longer) idiom over a standard construct for fear of typos.

Comment: My answer was meant for usability of the `cat` syntax when entering individual commands in bash

Comment: @Adam if he was to write for speed he would not use bash in the first place. It's "known-inefficient".

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb then if my car is not the less pollutant one I should as well use coal as fuel? No, even when not choosing the best efficient thing, efficiency can still matters.